# Check if property is an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, properties, indexing

I want to check if a property from a class is an array (only concerned about numerical arrays here, NOT character arrays [i.e. strings]).  I then want to iterate through the array (i.e. 'do something' with each element).  See my attempt below.  Thanks!!

edit:
So, a little more info...  neither IsArray nor my method shown has worked thus far to check for an array.  MSDN suggestions "typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(type)", but I wasn't sure how to make that work with the property info here.  But maybe someone else knows how to use them and I just didn't use properly.

Within the "Class3" I define an array but to not dimension it.  I use "redim" when I instantiate it in another thread and load it up prior to passing it to this function. When I insert a breakpoint in the code here, I can look at "myobject" and see the array elements and values, but really I'm looking to cleanly use the propertyinfo type to generalize this method.  I also need to be able to index into the array once I've determined that it is an array...again using propertyinfo, not "myobject" directly.

```
Public Class Class2
Private Shared filelock As New Object
Public Shared Sub write2file(ByVal myobject As Class3)
    SyncLock filelock
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(File.Open(newfilename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            'Dim pinfo() As PropertyInfo = GetType(Class3).GetProperties
            Dim pinfo() As PropertyInfo = CType(myobject.GetType.GetRuntimeProperties, PropertyInfo())
            sb.Clear()
            For Each p As PropertyInfo In pinfo
                If Not p.GetIndexParameters.Length > 0 Then 'if property is not an array
                    sb.Append(p.GetValue(myobject)).Append(",")

                Else ' if property is an array
                    For x As Integer = 0 To p.GetIndexParameters.Length - 1
                        sb.Append(p.GetValue(myobject, New Object() {x})).Append(",") 'append each value from array to the stringbuilder in .CSV format
                    Next
                End If
            Next
            sw.WriteLine(sb) 'write string to file
        End Using

    End SyncLock

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Well, it depends. The array can have strings and numbers. What would you like to do with either of them? I see how your checking for the length of an array, that's fine. Do you only want to check if it's numerical when it's an array or both???

Comment: You can try using [`IsArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isarray.aspx) function to check if a property is of type array or not. `IsArray()` **won't return `True` for String property** (because it is recognized as array of Char) as you seems concerned about

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is not the prettiest thing to do (I somehow don't feel comfortable when comparing the type with a string... if anyone knows better please let me know), but I have tested it and it works:

```
For Each p As PropertyInfo In pinfo
    Dim typeString As String = p.PropertyType.Name.ToString
    If typeString = "Int32[]" Then 'if property is not an array
        sb.Append(p.GetValue(myobject)).Append(",")
    Else ' if property is an array
        For x As Integer = 0 To p.GetIndexParameters.Length - 1
            sb.Append(p.GetValue(myobject, New Object() {x})).Append(",") 'append each value from array to the stringbuilder in .CSV format
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Is it what you were looking for?

---

> only concerned about numerical arrays here, NOT character arrays [i.e. strings]

If by "numerical" you mean that it could be any type (not just Integer), and you are 100% sure that the array it is either numerical or string (I mean, no boolean arrays for instance), then you can modify it to this:

```
If typeString.EndsWith("[]") And typeString <> "String[]" Then
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: I was not able to get this to work. First....."If typeString = "Int32[]" Then 'if property is not an array" should the be case "if property is an array", but you have reversed these so I'm not sure how it worked for you. When I tried this before (and now using your solution), it just prints the "system.single[]" for each array.

Comment: second: The lines: "For x As Integer = 0 To p.GetIndexParameters.Length - 1  ..........................."doesn't work because the "p.GetIndexParameters.Length" doesn't actually work to return the array lengths. I had tried this without luck.

Comment: First of all, my bad. There is an error in the my code: it should be `Dim typeString As String = p.PropertyType.Name.ToString` so it doesn't bother you with the "System." part. I will edit my answer right now. _it just prints the "system.single[]" for each array._ : doesn't it mean an array of type "single"? Thus being a numeric array. This is why I strongly suggest using the second part of the answer if you are sure that it is either a numerical array or a string array. I did not really check the behavior of the Append, just the "number array" recognition as the question asked...

Answer (score -1):

Replace the If block with something like this and it seems to work with a trivial Class3 implementation with an Int32() array property:

```
If p.PropertyType.IsArray Then
  ' Untested loop code for array case
Else
  ' Untested code for scalar (non-array) case
End If
```

No one seems to have recommended the PropertyType property yet, but that's pretty crucial.